# Plugin crash with Ruby in redmine_print_issue plugin

Tags: debian, redmine

my configuration in redmine, i'm install plugin and getting an error

```
Environment:
Redmine version                3.3.5.stable
Ruby version                   2.3.4-p301 (2017-03-30) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version                  4.2.7.1
Environment                    production
Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
Subversion                     1.8.10
Git                            2.1.4
redmine_print_issue            2.0.4
```

**Plugin crashing 500 Internal Server Error
    NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):**

> plugins/redmine_print_issue/lib/redmine_print_issue/patches/
>   issues_controller_pa
>   tch.rb:24:in `show_with_print'
>   lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in`sudo_mode'
>   in

I'm dont known Ruby(

```
module RedminePrintIssue
  module Patches

    module IssuesControllerPatch
      def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

        base.class_eval do
          Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text", 
:odt, [], %w(odt)
          alias_method_chain :show, :print
        end
      end

      module InstanceMethods
        def show_with_print
          if request.formats.include? :odt then
            ofile = Tempfile.new('print_template')
            begin
              qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new(url_for @order)
              imgfile = Tempfile.new('print_template_image')
              imgfile.write qrcode.as_svg
              @issue.class_eval('def images=(images); @images=images; end')
              @issue.images = { "qrcode" => imgfile.path }
              @issue.render_odt 
@issue.odt_path(Setting.plugin_redmine_print_issue["tracker_#
{@issue.tracker_id.to_s}_template"]+'.odt'), ofile.path
              respond_to do |format|
                format.odt { send_file ofile.path, type: "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text", filename: "##{@issue.id} #{@issue.subject}.odt" }
              end
            ensure
              ofile.close
              imgfile.close
            end
          else
            show_without_print
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end

unless IssuesController.included_modules.include?(RedminePrintIssue::Patches::IssuesControllerPatch)
  IssuesController.send(:include, RedminePrintIssue::Patches::IssuesControllerPatch)
end
```

help me plz

Answer (score 0):

The plugin does not correctly instantiate its default values in the settings (the template names are missing).
Only checking the checkbox (which will enable the Print button for your tracker) will not trigger storing the template name which then results in the error you are experiencing.

Simple workaround around this: Change the button text (you can change it back afterwards) and then press 'Apply' - this will trigger storing the template name.

BTW of course you should go for your own templates as the example template is just that: an example